# code works on emulator, but dont run on real devices

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

So, when I run my project on Android Emulator - all works perfect. But when I tested project on two smartphones - this part of code always does not work as it should. This fragment must show some information about transaction from server. That is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R57U.png) from emulator. And this is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1tUF.jpg) from one of my smartphones. There are same .apk file for both tests. Sometimes, on real device all can run normal, but I dont get, how it works. I had tried to clean/rebuild project. Other fragments work normal, so it's not about server or sid.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.Penok.API.APIUtils;
import com.Penok.API.Model;
import com.Penok.API.PenyokService;
import com.Penok.API.TransactionsListModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class TransactionsFragment extends Fragment {

private PenyokService transactionsService;
private RecyclerView transactionsRecyclerView;
private TransactionsAdapter transactionsAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> authorNames;
private ArrayList<String> payeeNames;
private ArrayList<String> payerNames; 
private ArrayList<TransactionsListModel> transactions;
private int authorCounter = 0;
private int payeeCounter = 0;
private int payerCounter = 0;
private int size = 0;

public TransactionsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    transactionsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle, container, false);

    transactionsService = APIUtils.getPService();
    transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    authorNames = new ArrayList<>();
    payeeNames = new ArrayList<>();
    payerNames = new ArrayList<>();


    transactionsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle, container, false);
    transactionsAdapter = new TransactionsAdapter(new ArrayList<TransactionsListModel>(0),
            new ArrayList<String>(0), new ArrayList<String>(0), new ArrayList<String>(0));
    transactionsRecyclerView.setAdapter(transactionsAdapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    transactionsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadTransactions();

    return transactionsRecyclerView;
}

private void loadTransactions() {
    transactionsService.getTransactionsHistory(MainActivity.getSid()).enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                if (response.body().getTransactionsList() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    transactions.addAll(response.body().getTransactionsList());
                    size = transactions.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); i++) {
                        loadNames(transactions.get(i).getAuthor(), "author");
                        loadNames(transactions.get(i).getPayee(), "payee");
                        loadNames(transactions.get(i).getPayer(), "payer");
                    }
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                needToUpdate(authorCounter, payeeCounter, payerCounter,
                        size, transactions, authorNames, payeeNames, payerNames);

                // transactionsAdapter.updateTransactions(response.body().getTransactionsList());
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "loadTransactions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void loadNames(final int id, final String key){
    transactionsService.getUserName(id, MainActivity.getSid()).enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                switch (key) {
                    case "author":
                        authorNames.add(response.body().getNameFor());
                        authorCounter++;
                        break;
                    case "payee":
                        payeeNames.add(response.body().getNameFor());
                        payeeCounter++;
                        break;
                    case "payer":
                        payerNames.add(response.body().getNameFor());
                        payerCounter++;
                        break;
                }
                //transactionsAdapter.updateTransactions(response.body().getTransactionsList());
                needToUpdate(authorCounter, payeeCounter, payerCounter, size,
                        transactions, authorNames, payeeNames, payerNames);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "loadNames", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void needToUpdate(int authorCounter,
                          int payeeCounter,
                          int payerCounter,
                          int size,
                          List<TransactionsListModel> response,
                          ArrayList<String> authorNames,
                          ArrayList<String> payeeNames,
                          ArrayList<String> payerNames){
    if ((authorCounter == size) && (payeeCounter == size) && (payerCounter == size)) {
        transactionsAdapter.updateTransactions(response, authorNames, payeeNames, payerNames);
    }
}

}
```

Also, on real devices show two toasts (that have been added to test this issue):

- not null
- loadNames

Comment: Is it throwing any error in the Toast from onFailureListener() when you are testing in the real device. And is your real device is connected to the internet properly?

Comment: A couple of times I've seen an error "outOfTimeException", but I'm not sure
And yes, internet works fine, because other methods in another fragments makes all immediately

Also, it throws something not in onFailure, but on else's branch from if(response.isSuccessful())

Comment: Now you have this problem i.e., readTimeOutException this means somehow your sever is not working fine or the time you have specified is less for your device to read the data.

Comment: but why this happening only in one fragment and only on real devices? I tested it on wi-fi and on mobile internet (both are fast)
Also, timeOutException was only several times. Now it's about else's branch from if(response.isSuccessful()), so, it's something with response from loadNames(), as I think

Comment: I'll will tell you it sometime happens, I've been AsynchHTTPClient() to call the apis and get the response before that I explicitly set the timeout for the client before calling the api like this `client.setTimeOut() and client.setMaxTimeOut();` in order to be free from this problem